# Floating point results

Tags: c, floating-point

In my C code:

I see some of the results in floating point come out to be for example `2.404567E+1`. it seems to me that for results less then 1 the results turn out to be in some exponential series.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. how can I get the result rounded off to some digits ie instead of `5.23542342734` I just want the result to be `5.23`
2. How can I get rid of exponential results and get results as for example `0.1648` instead of `1.6483517E-1`

Comment: can we stop with the floating point questions already?

Comment: @Woot4Moo, did you never start, having questions like this? Can´t we better suggest to first search for questions already answered before new dupes are posted so there are less questions to stop with?

Comment: @TheBlastOne I have made my fair share of mistakes on SO and been dealt with appropriately. Perhaps before someone posts they could use the predictive feature to let them know that there are similar questions on this site.

Comment: @Woot4Moo 100% agree, however, that point was in your first comment only if one already got the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust format string:

```
 printf ("%.2f", float_data);
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Or to use to truncate/approximate the value to some decimal places, i think the following should work:

```
trunc = floor (float_val * 10000) / 10000;
```

The above will preserve only upto 4 decimal places of `float_var` and store it to `trunc`. Use `round ()` if needed.

Comment: answer lacks confidence because did not think about any side effects which might creep in, but mathematically its the way. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can control the output format of `printf()` (I'm assuming you're talking about `printf()`?) in a number of ways.  e.g.:

```
printf("%.2f\n", 5.23542342734);  // Prints "5.23"
printf("%.4f\n", 1.6483517E-1);   // Prints "0.1648"
```

See e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ (or a million other references out there on the internet) for more details on format specifiers for `printf()`.

Comment: I do not use printf, I get the value directly in the variable and whose address is used by the caller to grab this value. So, why do we ger exponential results, why not 0.123?

Comment: if you do not use `printf` how can you see the contents of the variable ?

Comment: @coder: If you're not printing it out, then how are you seeing "1.6483517E-1"?

Comment: @coder: Er... You seem to be trapped in some serious misconcepon. You claim that you get the above undesirable results directly in the variable (as opposed to what is printed by `printf`). That just doesn't make any sense. All you are talking about (exponential format, digits etc.) are specific properties of *string representation* of the number, i.e, of what `printf` generates (or other string-related functions). The variable itself, until it is converted  to string, has no specific representation like the one you describe. Please, clarify what you mean. At this time it is completely unclear.

Comment: @coder: Needless to say, you can't see the content of the variable until you convert it to string of characters in one way or another. So, despite your claims, you *are* using `printf` or some similar format conversion function explicitly or implicitly. You just don't realize that. The "problems" you observe are introduced by that conversion function. They have noting (or very little) to do with the variables themselves.

Comment: Well he could stare at the float values in his debugger.